# How to add functionality so woocommerce orders are visible to a driver user-role in the same city?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have a WordPress Woo-commerce store with the Pro version of the delivery drivers for woo-commerce plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/delivery-drivers-for-woocommerce/).

Everything works fine as any user who is of user role : 'delivery driver' can view and claim all orders that are processed through the website, at the moment using woo-commerce delivery/shipping zones settings I have configured it so only customers who reside in a certain city can place an order and I am only approving delivery drivers in that area.

But I want to roll this out to other cities, I can add the postcodes so users can order from those postcodes but the problem is with the delivery drivers plugin - drivers will see all orders from all cities in their dashboard. I only want the drivers to view and claim orders in the city they reside in (the city they have assigned themselves to).

Here is the code to the functionality that displays all orders placed on the website to user role type 'delivery driver' :

**driver-dashboard-shortcode.php**

```
<?php
/**
* The Unclaimed Orders Shortcode.

**/

function ddwc_pro_dashboard_shortcode() {

// Check if user is logged in.
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Get the user ID.
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Get the user object.
    $user_meta = get_userdata( $user_id );

    // If user_id doesn't equal zero.
    if ( 0 != $user_id ) {

        // If claim delivery button is pushed.
        if ( ! empty( $_GET['claim_delivery'] ) ) {

            // Get deliver ID to claim.
            $claim_delivery = $_GET['claim_delivery'];

            // Update order status.
            $order = wc_get_order( $claim_delivery );
            $order->update_status( 'driver-assigned' );

            // Update order with driver ID.
            update_post_meta( $claim_delivery, 'ddwc_driver_id', $user_id, -1 );

            // Redirect URL.
            $redirect_url = apply_filters( 'ddwc_pro_claim_order_redirect_url', get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ) ) . '/driver-dashboard/?orderid=' . $claim_delivery, $claim_delivery );

            // Redirect driver to the order details.
            wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
        }

        // Get all the user roles as an array.
        $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;

        // Check if the role you're interested in, is present in the array.
        if ( in_array( 'driver', $user_roles, true ) ) {

            // Set variable for driver ID.
            if ( isset( $_GET['orderid'] ) && ( '' != $_GET['orderid'] ) ) {
                $driver_id = get_post_meta( $_GET['orderid'], 'ddwc_driver_id', true );
            }

            /**
             * Args for Orders with no driver ID attached.
             */
            $args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'shop_order',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_status'    => 'any',
                'post_parent'    => 0
            );

            /**
             * Get Orders with Driver ID attached
             */
            $unclaimed_orders = get_posts( $args );

            /**
             * If there are orders to loop through.
             */
            if ( $unclaimed_orders ) {

                // Total for table thead.
                $total_title = '<td>' . esc_attr__( 'Total', 'ddwc' ) . '</td>';

                do_action( 'ddwc_pro_unclaimed_orders_table_before' );

                echo '<table class="ddwc-dashboard">';
                echo '<thead><tr><td>' . esc_attr__( 'Date', 'ddwc-pro' ) . '</td><td>' . esc_attr__( 'Address', 'ddwc-pro' ) . '</td>' . apply_filters( 'ddwc_pro_driver_dashboard_unclaimed_orders_total_title', $total_title ) . '<td></td></tr></thead>';
                echo '<tbody>';

                do_action( 'ddwc_pro_unclaimed_orders_table_tbody_before' );

                foreach ( $unclaimed_orders as $driver_order ) {

                    // Get Driver ID (if set).
                    $driver_id_setting = get_post_meta( $driver_order->ID, 'ddwc_driver_id', TRUE );

                    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object.
                    $order = wc_get_order( $driver_order->ID );

                    // Get the required order data.
                    $order_data         = $order->get_data();
                    $currency_code      = $order_data['currency'];
                    $currency_symbol    = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $currency_code );
                    $order_id           = $order_data['id'];
                    $order_status       = $order_data['status'];
                    $order_date_created = $order_data['date_created']->date( 'm-d-Y' );

                    ## CART INFORMATION:

                    $order_total = $order_data['total'];

                    ## BILLING INFORMATION:

                    $order_billing_city     = $order_data['billing']['city'];
                    $order_billing_state    = $order_data['billing']['state'];
                    $order_billing_postcode = $order_data['billing']['postcode'];

                    ## SHIPPING INFORMATION:

                    $order_shipping_city     = $order_data['shipping']['city'];
                    $order_shipping_state    = $order_data['shipping']['state'];
                    $order_shipping_postcode = $order_data['shipping']['postcode'];

                    // Create address to use in the table.
                    $address = $order_billing_city . ' ' . $order_billing_state . ', ' . $order_billing_postcode;

                    // Set address to shipping (if available).
                    if ( isset( $order_shipping_city ) ) {
                        $address = $order_shipping_city . ' ' . $order_shipping_state . ', ' . $order_shipping_postcode;
                    }

                    // Allowed statuses.
                    $status_array = apply_filters( 'ddwc_pro_driver_dashboard_unclaimed_orders_status_array', array( 'processing' ) );

                    // Display unassigned orders.
                    if ( in_array( $order_status, $status_array ) && ( -1 == $driver_id_setting || '' === $driver_id_setting ) ) {
                        echo '<tr>';

                        echo '<td>' . $order_date_created . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . apply_filters( 'ddwc_pro_driver_dashboard_unclaimed_orders_table_address', $address ) . '</td>';

                        if ( isset( $order_total ) ) {
                            $order_total = '<td>'  . $currency_symbol . $order_total . '</td>';
                            echo apply_filters( 'ddwc_pro_driver_dashboard_unclaimed_orders_total', $order_total );
                        } else {
                            echo '<td>-</td>';
                        }

                        echo '<td><a href="' . apply_filters( 'ddwc_pro_driver_dashboard_unclaimed_orders_button_url', '?claim_delivery=' . $order_id, $order_id ) . '" class="button">' . apply_filters( 'ddwc_pro_driver_dashboard_unclaimed_orders_button_text', __( 'CLAIM', 'ddwc-pro' ) ) . '</a></td>';

                        echo '</tr>';
                    } else {
                        // Do nothing.
                    }
                }

                do_action( 'ddwc_pro_unclaimed_orders_table_tbody_after' );

                echo '</tbody>';
                echo '</table>';

                do_action( 'ddwc_pro_unclaimed_orders_table_after' );

                // Driver dashboard button.
                $dashboard_button = '<a href="' . apply_filters( 'ddwc_pro_back_to_driver_dashboard_link', get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ) ) . 'driver-dashboard/' ) . '">&larr; ' . __( 'Driver Dashboard', 'ddwc-pro' ) . '</a>';

                // Filter "Driver Dashboard" button.
                echo apply_filters( 'ddwc_pro_back_to_driver_dashboard_button', $dashboard_button );

            } else {

                do_action( 'ddwc_pro_assigned_orders_empty_before' );

                // Message - No assigned orders.
                $empty  = '<h3 class="ddwc assigned-orders">' . __( 'Assigned Orders', 'ddwc-pro' ) . '</h3>';
                $empty .= '<p>' . __( 'You do not have any assigned orders.', 'ddwc-pro' ) . '</p>';

                echo apply_filters( 'ddwc_pro_assigned_orders_empty', $empty );

                do_action( 'ddwc_pro_assigned_orders_empty_after' );

            }
        } else {

            // Set the Access Denied page text.
            $access_denied = '<h3 class="ddwc access-denied">' . __( 'Access Denied', 'ddwc-pro' ) . '</h3><p>' . __( 'Sorry, but you are not able to view this page.', 'ddwc-pro' ) . '</p>';

            // Filter Access Denied text.
            echo apply_filters( 'ddwc_access_denied', $access_denied );
        }

    } else {
        // Do nothing.
    }
} else {
    apply_filters( 'ddwc_pro_dashboard_login_form', wp_login_form() );
}
}
add_shortcode( 'ddwc_pro_dashboard', 'ddwc_pro_dashboard_shortcode' );
```

I had thought of a way to implement this functionality - I have created a custom field (just for delivery drivers) in the woocommerce  account details section 'my-account/edit-account'. The field is a dropdown list of cities a delivery driver can assign to himself in his account details.

And I want to call a function that checks if the 'town/city' address label matches the selected city in a drivers profile, if it does then the driver can see that order (orders). If a driver has not selected a city in that drop-down then he will not see any orders.

Here is how I have added the drop-down city list:

```
  <?php

   /**
   * Get additional account fields.
   *
   * @return array
   */
   function iconic_get_account_fields() {
    return apply_filters( 'iconic_account_fields', array(
        'city_select'              => array(
           'type'                  => 'select',
           'label'                 => __( 'Select City', 'iconic' ),
           'hide_in_account'       => false,
            'hide_in_admin'        => false,
            'required'             => false,
           'options' => array(
               ''    => __( 'Select an option...', 'iconic' ),
               1     => __( 'Manchester', 'iconic' ),
               2     => __( 'Birmingham', 'iconic' ),
               3     => __( 'London', 'iconic' ),
           ),
        'bank_name'                 => array(
            'type'                 => 'text',
            'label'                => __( 'Bank Name', 'iconic' ),
            'hide_in_account'      => false,
            'hide_in_admin'        => false,
            'required'             => false,
        ),

    ) );
}

/**
 * Add post values to account fields if set.
 *
 * @param array $fields
 *
 * @return array
 */
function iconic_add_post_data_to_account_fields( $fields ) {
    if ( empty( $_POST ) ) {
        return $fields;
    }

    foreach ( $fields as $key => $field_args ) {
        if ( empty( $_POST[ $key ] ) ) {
            $fields[ $key ]['value'] = '';
            continue;
        }

        $fields[ $key ]['value'] = $_POST[ $key ];
    }

    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'iconic_account_fields', 'iconic_add_post_data_to_account_fields', 10, 1 );

/**
 * Add field to account area.
 */
function iconic_print_user_frontend_fields() {
    $fields            = iconic_get_account_fields();
    $is_user_logged_in = is_user_logged_in();

    foreach ( $fields as $key => $field_args ) {
        $value = null;

        if ( ! iconic_is_field_visible( $field_args ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        if ( $is_user_logged_in ) {
            $user_id = iconic_get_edit_user_id();
            $value   = iconic_get_userdata( $user_id, $key );
        }

        $value = isset( $field_args['value'] ) ? $field_args['value'] : $value;

        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field_args, $value );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'iconic_print_user_frontend_fields', 10 ); // my account

/**
 * Get user data.
 *
 * @param $user_id
 * @param $key
 *
 * @return mixed|string
 */
function iconic_get_userdata( $user_id, $key ) {
    if ( ! iconic_is_userdata( $key ) ) {
        return get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, true );
    }

    $userdata = get_userdata( $user_id );

    if ( ! $userdata || ! isset( $userdata->{$key} ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    return $userdata->{$key};
}


/**
 * Get currently editing user ID (frontend account/edit profile/edit other user).
 *
 * @return int
 */
function iconic_get_edit_user_id() {
    return isset( $_GET['user_id'] ) ? (int) $_GET['user_id'] : get_current_user_id();
}


/**
 * Save registration fields.
 *
 * @param int $customer_id
 */
function iconic_save_account_fields( $customer_id ) {
    $fields         = iconic_get_account_fields();
    $sanitized_data = array();

    foreach ( $fields as $key => $field_args ) {
        if ( ! iconic_is_field_visible( $field_args ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $sanitize = isset( $field_args['sanitize'] ) ? $field_args['sanitize'] : 'wc_clean';
        $value    = isset( $_POST[ $key ] ) ? call_user_func( $sanitize, $_POST[ $key ] ) : '';

        if ( iconic_is_userdata( $key ) ) {
            $sanitized_data[ $key ] = $value;
            continue;
        }

        update_user_meta( $customer_id, $key, $value );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $sanitized_data ) ) {
        $sanitized_data['ID'] = $customer_id;
        wp_update_user( $sanitized_data );
    }
}


add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'iconic_save_account_fields' ); // edit own account admin
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'iconic_save_account_fields' ); // edit other account
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'iconic_save_account_fields' ); // edit WC account

/**
 * Is this field core user data.
 *
 * @param $key
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function iconic_is_userdata( $key ) {
    $userdata = array(
        'user_pass',
        'user_login',
        'user_nicename',
        'user_url',
        'user_email',
        'display_name',
        'nickname',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'description',
        'rich_editing',
        'user_registered',
        'role',
        'jabber',
        'aim',
        'yim',
        'show_admin_bar_front',
    );

    return in_array( $key, $userdata );
}

/**
 * Is field visible.
 *
 * @param $field_args
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function iconic_is_field_visible( $field_args ) {
    $visible = true;
    $action  = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'action' );

    if ( is_admin() && ! empty( $field_args['hide_in_admin'] ) ) {
        $visible = false;
    } elseif ( ( is_account_page() || $action === 'save_account_details' ) && is_user_logged_in() && ! empty( $field_args['hide_in_account'] ) ) {
        $visible = false;
    } 

    return $visible;
}

/**
 * Add fields to admin area.
 */
function iconic_print_user_admin_fields() {
    $fields = iconic_get_account_fields();
    ?>
    <h2><?php _e( 'Additional Information', 'iconic' ); ?></h2>
    <table class="form-table" id="iconic-additional-information">
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ( $fields as $key => $field_args ) { ?>
            <?php
            if ( ! iconic_is_field_visible( $field_args ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            $user_id = iconic_get_edit_user_id();
            $value   = iconic_get_userdata( $user_id, $key );
            ?>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label for="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $field_args['label']; ?></label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <?php $field_args['label'] = false; ?>
                    <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field_args, $value ); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'iconic_print_user_admin_fields', 30 ); // admin: edit profile
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'iconic_print_user_admin_fields', 30 ); // admin: edit other users

/**
 * Validate fields on frontend.
 *
 * @param WP_Error $errors
 *
 * @return WP_Error
 */
function iconic_validate_user_frontend_fields( $errors ) {
    $fields = iconic_get_account_fields();

    foreach ( $fields as $key => $field_args ) {
        if ( empty( $field_args['required'] ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        if ( ! isset( $_POST['register'] ) && ! empty( $field_args['hide_in_account'] ) ) {
            continue;
        }

    
        if ( empty( $_POST[ $key ] ) ) {
            $message = sprintf( __( '%s is a required field.', 'iconic' ), '<strong>' . $field_args['label'] . '</strong>' );
            $errors->add( $key, $message );
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_save_account_details_errors', 'iconic_validate_user_frontend_fields', 10 )
```

I am a novice to programming (especially PHP) I have tried different ways in adding a if statement to check if I can make functionality where before it displays the list of orders in the table, it checks if the drivers selected city matches the city in the customers address and then displays the same orders as the city the driver resides in, if not no orders should be displayed.

But I keep breaking my site, any assistance would be appreciated (as im beginning to think maybe this is not the file to add this sort of function).

Comment: Which different ways have you tried adding this logic?  Any additional information will make it easier to help.

As I see it, it seems like you are off to a good start - you just need to get the driver account information (looks like that is by calling `iconic_get_userdata`) and then inside the loop of unclaimed orders: `foreach ( $unclaimed_orders as $driver_order ) {...` check if the order shipping address city matches (assuming I understood the problem correctly).

Comment: One possible solution could be to modify the $args array, adding a "where" clause to only show orders within range of the driver.
The logic would be as such: "where order.postcode in $arrayOfPostcodesNearDriver".  


$arrayOfPostcodesNearDriver = get_postcode_api($driver_postcode, $allowed_range).  

This solution allows drivers to work in one or more close by area, depending on the range limit you define.  

I'll try to code up something on the weekend if I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

On the site options side (custom, or trough woocommerce delivery zone options):

- Admin store a list of cities, with name and ID
- You could do an ACF option field list, where you can fill a City name, and an ID (or postcode) (to prevent make queries based on cities name only)
- Woocommerce also has delivery options where you can store shipping areas, so you could store your cities here and use them. Depending on how you integrated with Woocommerce.

On the user/driver side:

- Your additional city field should let the user be able to select multiple cities from the list you defined
- Data will store as a user_meta a serialized array of IDs or Postcode from selected cities
- So each driver has a postcode/IDs of cities stored as user meta, that he can edits

On the order checkout process side :

- If the postcode of delivery address is "locked" to the available cities list you made: great
- If the postcode is a free field, you'll need to add something so the order is associated with a postcode/ID of the available city you've defined. To be able to match drivers and orders.
- Depending on your checkout process, you could add an order field so the customer selects a city based on your admin list. Or make the postal_code field limited to your list. You need something so an order can be matched to one of the cities from your list.

On the driver orders list page :

- You'll edit the WP_query querying that query orders, to add a meta_query
- meta_query will query orders based on the postcode/IDs of user_meta from the current user driver
- You are able to foreach on the user meta array values, and add meta_query "OR" for each drivers cities ID/Postcode to the orders query
- order matching one of the driver's city IDs/postcodes will be displayed